# Android Gridview - establecer dinámicamente borde en imágenes

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-gridview

Intento establecerle en borde a unos imageview dentro de un Gridview (utilizando el adaptador para del Gridview).

Cuando hago clic en el imageview (con padding de 7dp) que deseo seleccionar, intento establecer el borde con `imgView.setBackground` asignando un recurso *Drawable* con un "shape" de tipo rectangular, grosor de 7dp y color sólido, pero no funciona.

¿Por qué el setbackground no está estableciendo el borde?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los `shapes` también tienen que ser creados dinámicamente dentro del `adapter`. Un ejemplo:

```
GradientDrawable shape1 = new GradientDrawable();
shape1.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
//shape1.setCornerRadii(new float[]{20, 20, 20, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0});  //para esquinas redondeadas
shape1.setColor(Color.parseColor("#b4b2a8"));      // el color debe ser en hexadecimal
shape1.setStroke(6, Color.parseColor("#b0b7d9"));

imgView.setBackground(shape1);       // y seteas el background con ese shape
```

Comment: Funcionó más o menos, en sí es así como se menciona, pero el problema que estoy obteniendo es que solamente está quedando con el borde el elemento 5 sin importar cuáles seleccione.